# What is the true signature of SendMessage, and how should it be invoked in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

There are conflicting sources of information on the proper signature for the Win32 [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Microsoft's winapi documentation states that its signature is the following:

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(
    _In_ HWND hWnd, 
    _In_ UINT Msg, 
    _In_ WPARAM wParam, 
    _In_ LPARAM lParam );
```

So we have the following types to resolve:

- `LRESULT`
- `WPARAM`
- `LPARAM`

Using Microsoft's '[Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)' page, I was able to make some findings.

---

`LRESULT` is typed as a `LONG_PTR`. `LONG_PTR` has the following definition:

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef __int64 LONG_PTR; 
#else
 typedef long LONG_PTR;
#endif
```

`long` in winapi is always a 32-bit signed quantity, according to that same '[Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)' page.

---

Next up is `WPARAM`, which is typed as a `UINT_PTR`. `UINT_PTR` has the following definition:

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef unsigned __int64 UINT_PTR;
#else
 typedef unsigned int UINT_PTR;
#endif
```

`int` (just like `long`) in winapi is always a 32-bit signed quantity.

---

Lastly, `LPARAM`, which is typed as another `LONG_PTR`.

So, to summarize, we have:

- `LRESULT` -> `LONG_PTR` -> signed 32-bit/64-bit depending on platform.
- `WPARAM` -> `UINT_PTR` -> unsigned 32-bit/64-bit depending on platform.
- `LPARAM` -> `LONG_PTR` -> signed 32-bit/64-bit depending on platform.

And thus our signature in C# (ignoring signedness) would be:

```
[DllImport( "User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto )]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage( IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
```

P-Invoke.Net's [documentation on `SendMessage`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) corroborates this - they have nearly the same signature, excepting signedness, and their documentation has this to say:

> 2) **NEVER use "int" or "integer" as lParam**. Your code WILL crash on 64-bit windows. ONLY use IntPtr, a "ref" structure, or an "out" structure.
>   3) NEVER use "bool", "int", or "integer" as the return value. Your core WILL crash on 64-bit windows. ONLY use IntPtr. It's not safe to use bool - pInvoke cannot marshal an IntPtr to a boolean.

So far everything makes sense.

However, two pieces of information disagree with this.

One, my own code, which has run in 64-bit and 32-bit for months without crashing, has used `int wparam` and `int lparam`. Why hasn't this crashed?

Two, in **Microsoft's own source code**, [`System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,053af6fcd6cf0cc7), we see many, many definitions violate this analysis. The worst of which is on line 1044:

```
[DllImport(ExternDll.User32, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

They specifically declare `lParam` as an int, which should crash.

---

**What is the correct signature of `SendMessage`?**

**Is Microsoft's signature broken?**

**Why haven't the 'broken' signatures been causing crashes?**

Comment: You get away with it on 64 bit because it's a register calling convention. IntPtr is correct.

Comment: `lParam` and `wParam` is really `IntPtr` (pointer size values). if you pass *pointer* to some data in 64bit process and this pointer exceeds 32bit size - it will be truncated (if you declare it as *int* )and recipient of you message crash if reference data by this invalid pointer

Comment: @RbMm - your comment doesn't make sense, in the context of this question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: There's nothing much to explain. The message is int, everything else is pointer sized. End. Of. Story.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah but "You get away with it on 64 bit because it's a register calling convention" < this part is interesting for me.

Comment: Only get away with it if it's OK for the values to be truncated to 32 bits

Comment: The 64-bit calling convention on Windows stores the first few parameters of every function call in registers instead of on the stack, with one entire 64-bit register dedicated to each parameter (smaller parameters are not packed). [More information.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) MSDN will have all the information you need to understand the Windows 32-bit and 64-bit *application binary interfaces* (ABIs), which explains **everything** you ask in your question.

Comment: [Here is an additional explanation on why C/C++ `long` is always 32 bits on Windows.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563) Finally, note that all this information is specific to Windows. If you move to other platforms, you'll have to deal with different ABIs (usually the System V ABI, which most Unix-like OSs use).

Comment: @andlabs thanks, with your explanation I think I got - first 4 parameters are stored in 64-bit register so no harm is done (except value is potentially truncated). But if there were more parameters - the rest are stored on stack and that might cause real harm in OP's case.

Comment: @Andlabs - it'd be great if you put all of that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 64-bit Windows ([AMD64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx)) the [first 4 function parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx) are stored in CPU registers, they are not passed on the stack. These registers are always there and are always 64-bit wide so the actual call to the function is always going to be "valid". The content of the parameters however might not be valid.

- When a parameter is specified as `int` instead of `IntPtr` then the contents of the upper 32 bits are undefined. The compiler/marshaler is most likely going to generate a `mov` (copy into the register) that clears the upper 32 bits but there is no guarantee, future compiler optimizations might use that "free" space for something else.
- At run-time you are not going to see a crash most of the time, it is only going to happen if some memory is allocated outside of the first 4 GiB in the process address-space. You can force such an allocation by calling [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the `MEM_TOP_DOWN` flag. If the address does not fit in 32 bits then the address is going to get truncated and the code responding to the message is going to access the wrong address and is probably going to crash or corrupt memory or otherwise fail.

The return value is also stored in a register and has the same truncation issue.

I don't know why the broken signature is not causing crashes, perhaps they are only sending messages that do not use pointers? Or they are just getting lucky?